# A quick Poisson distribution problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A plane drops 535 bombs over 576 fields. How many fields were hit at least twice?

I have a feeling this is related to the Poisson distribution, but I'm having trouble identifying the variable which is Poisson distributed here. Is it simply the number of fields hit at least twice? But then what would the parameter be? Or is the the number of bombs dropped on any single field, then the number of fields hit at least twice is the probability of a single field being hit at least twice times the number of fields?

Comment: isn't the question a little inaccurate? "How many fields were hit at least twice" implies that there's a definite number of fields that were hit at least twice. Are you asking for the probability of more than one field being hit more than once?

Comment: The given data says that one expects $\frac{535}{576}$ bombs per field. The number of bombs per field is the Poisson distributed variable (and we have sampled it 576 times). The question is how often this Poisson variable can be expected to be $\ge2$ (that is neither 0 nor 1).

Comment: Given the data you've given it can well easily be 0.

Comment: Even if this is poisson distributed, which is by no means clear. Even if we assume that each field is equally likely to be hit (which would make them unusual fields hit by unusual bombs from an unusual plane) we have no idea of the variance.

Comment: That's literally all I was given. Maybe the question is asking for the expected number of fields hit at least twice? @DaleM, if it's Poisson distributed, then isn't the variance the same as the mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a Poisson model and cross our fingers. If $X$ is the number of bombs hitting a "field," the distribution of the random variable $X$ can, if aim is poor, be approximately modeled by a Poisson with parameter $\lambda=\frac{535}{576}$. The probability that $X\ge 2$ is then $p=1-e^{-\lambda}-e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^1}{1!}$
The **mean** number of fields with at least $2$ hits is then $576p$.

**Remark:** During the Second World War, central London was divided into a grid of equal-sized regions. A selection of $576$ of these was made. A study was done of the distribution of bomb hits (I think it was the V1 or V2, not aircraft-launched bombs).  The empirical distribution of the $537$ "hits" was reasonably consistent with the Poisson model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was my initial idea, although now that I look at how I worded it in the question, it doesn't look very clear!

Comment: @AndreNicolas It was V2 rockets analysed by R.D. Clarke in his textbook - the relevant page is http://www.actuaries.org.uk/system/files/documents/pdf/0481.pdf, it directly addresses the clustering fallacy - the human tendency to see patterns where there are none

Comment: @DaleM: Thank you! I am not changing the remark at the end, since people reading the answer have access to your valuable reference.

Comment: @AndreNicolas No, it was not V2 rockets as you state but V1s which was a different type of missile

Comment: @Auric: Conveniently, my remark at the end does not say it was V2, it just expresses lack of knowledge of what kind it was.